# Why does a + operation on two members of a template class cause a type mismatch error?

Tags: scala, generics

lately I've decided to port my project's codebase to Scala for performance reasons but just as I was getting started, I was stopped by an error I did not understand. This is the minimal amount of code that causes the error:

```
class Foo[A](var x: A) {
  def +(other: Foo[A]) = new Foo[A](this.x + other.x)
}
```

And the error itself:

```
test.scala:2: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: String
  def +(other: Foo[A]) = new Foo[A](this.x + other.x)
                                                   ^
```

After looking around, I found some forum posts about similar errors which were apparently caused by Scala implicitly converting the template type to a string(?).

Comment: How do you _"sum"_ two things of some generic type `A`, what if I create two `Foos` of `Users`, what is the addition of two `Users`? - You probably come from an untyped background, like **Python** or **JavaScript**. If so, **Scala** will be hard to use without training for a lot of things, including its stronger and complex typesystem and its functional paradigm. I will recommend you to start with some basic tutorials first. You probably want to express that `A` can only be numeric things, like `Int` or `Double`, that is doable, but you must understand a few things first.

Comment: If you're using Dotty, you can use union types to ensure that A is limited to a certain set of types, like `Int` and `Long`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, just like in C++, when I create an instance of the class with the template type filled in, I'd expect the compiler to find a + function which would accept two A params and return A (A is the type passed to the template).

Comment: @digitcrusher uhm, sorry I never got to templates on my limited experience with **C++**, but I can say you that doesn't work with generics on **Scala** _(nor in **Java** )_ if you say `Foo` can take any value of any type `A` that is it, your class has to be able to work for any type, not just for those that have an `+` method _(not function, there are many differences between those two terms)_. You can specify that restriction you want, with a couple of alternatives, it all comes down to polymorphism, I prefer **typeclasses**, but you can also use **iheritance** or **structural types**.

Comment: @digitcrusher as I said before, I would just suggest you to keep studying, sooner than later you will learn the mechanisms to model what you want. But, if you believe you are ready, I would suggest you to learn [**typeclasses**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html), then you may be interested in [**Numeric**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) - Sometime ago I wrote about the different forms of polymorphism on **Scala** and their tradeoffs: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Oh, I understand everything now. For Scala the definition of A is anything, it doesnt have to have a + method. I'll look into the concepts you listed. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Scala generic is not template. It does compile time type check and does not generate code on the fly like C++ compiler. You can use Numeric type class to do addition on numeric types

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the compiler doesn't have enough information about type `A` to know how to `+` two of them.

The reason for the confusing error message is that the compiler "knows" that everything has a `toString()` method and that type `String` has a `+` method. So why doesn't it convert both to type `String` and `+` them together? It's because the `A`-to-`String` transition is an implicit conversion and the compiler won't do more than one implicit conversion in order to resolve an expression.

Thus the `found:A, required:String` error. The compiler is saying, "I've already converted the first `A` to `String` in order to resolve the `+` method but, now that I've done that, I can't do it again on the 2nd `A` element."

---

There are a few different ways around this. Here's one.

```
class Foo[A:Numeric](var x: A) {
  def +(other: Foo[A]) =
    new Foo[A](implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(this.x, other.x))
}
```

`A` is restricted to types found in the `Numeric` type class. To add two `A`s together, pull the implementation for `Numeric[A]` out of the implicit scope and invoke its `plus()` method.

Comment: So, how would I go about solving this error? Do I use one of those "refinement" things from the Tour of Scala? Btw, I'm aware of what implicit conversions are, we have lots of them in C++

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the plus method in `this.x + other.x` is not the plus method defined in Foo[A]. It comes from `A`. And as `A` is still undefined, can be `Any`. The compiler, as always, will look a way to make things compile and in this case will find a conversion that will allow `this.x` call to `+` method. It will find this in `Predef.scala` that is in scope and has

`implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
    def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
  }`

Therefore if `this.x` is a `String` to be able to concatenate `that.x`, it should also be a String. Which is not the case.

You can check it in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/706ef1b291134a5e5bce2275df2c222261f73451/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L381